# PowerShell script doubles the size of the output file from python script

Tags: python, powershell, encoding

Not too familiar with Python or PowerShell to start with. Basically I have a PowerShell script that runs a python script on a daily cycle.

PowerShell script:
py 'Path\to\script.py'

The python script uses df.to_excel to write a .xlsx file from a data frame. Normally the output file is roughly 40,000kb. When I run it with the PowerShell script, it almost doubles it at around 78,000kb.

Does anyone know why this is happening and how to fix this issue?

Tried running it in PowerShell 7 because I read it may be an encoding issue with PowerShell 5 (ps7 uses UTF8) but it was the same result. Running it manually through a python interpreter works

Comment: It is the Python script that actually generates the file? And the PowerShell script does nothing except run the Python script? Why not just run the Python script without PowerShell then?

Comment: First time using this site so I hope I'm replying correctly,  but yes the python script generates the excel file. It needs to be automated to run daily, but I'm unaware of another way to schedule the script to run besides using PowerShell and task scheduler.

Comment: You can run Python directly from the Task Scheduler, [see here](https://www.jcchouinard.com/python-automation-using-task-scheduler/).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the 2-minute [tour]. 
Moreover, open [Help] and read at least [ask]. Then, [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: Even running it in python through the task scheduler resulted in the doubled file size